# Source() in shiny apps

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having trouble calling the `source()` function in shiny.

The ideia is that the user, based on a `text input` (in this case, `input$textinput`), see some details on the subject he typed, like maps and datatables of it.

here's the code of how it works inside an `observeEvent`

```
observeEvent(input$search, {
    source("maps.R", local = TRUE)
    source("graphs.R", local = TRUE)}
```

At first i realized that i needed to set the argument `local = true` inside `source()`. It then recognized the `input$textinput`, but still wouldn't load the maps and the graphs as it was supposed to.

I then realized that when i call the `source()` the objects didn't load into the `global enviroment`.

Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What's in the files you are sourcing?

Comment: Are you trying to load new data based on the search inputs? Or new function definitions?